# How to print from arcpad without buying more Esri sofware?

Tags: open-source-gis, printing, maps, arcpad

I am running ArcPad 10 in windows 7 on a laptop and on a field unit consisting of an Ashtech MobileMapper 10 as a PDA talking to an SXBlue GPS.  This system provides the real time half meter (without post processing)  resolution I need for forestry and wetland science.  I can download data to Surfer for contouring applications but I can't print directly from Arcpad.

MapWindow  seemed to offer a solution but there's glitch in the latest release (4.8.6).  The glitch causes an apparent disparity between the numbers of lines in the dbf and shapefiles.  I don't see a way to load my project into the Esri cloud application and print from there.

Besides, I'd like to use this issue as an opportunity to learn an open source application and begin using it.

Answer (score 2):

There are many opensource GIS desktop applications options (QGIS, GRASS, gvSIG...etc).

You may find some here:

[OSGEO](http://www.osgeo.org/)

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend [QGIS](http://www.qgis.org). A lot of work has been done recently on the Print Composer tools, and they are becoming quite complete.

Answer (score 1):

Try [ArcGIS Explorer Desktop](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/explorer). It as some really reduced functionality of ArcMap, but you can add data, view attributes, make some very basic maps.

I've found it's a pretty good system for our field crew, who aren't the best with computers, due to its simplified interface.

If your looking for a more advanced GIS platform, go with @Darren Cope as QGIS is a pretty handy GIS software.